# Asp.net(C#), how to do sql statement that order by a counted field

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I’m working on a project which is an online shop,
I want to show in a page the most sold items,
So my sql is

```
Select (*), Count(Product_ID) as n from Order_Details order by n desc.
```

But it doesn’t work. Can someone help?

Comment: Internetic shop? :)

Comment: What is an *"internetic shop"* and what does *"But that doesn’t work."* mean? What does your data-structure look like? Why are you using `Select *`? etc...

Comment: Are you grouping here? that isn't valid SQL - there is no source table/expression, and you're doing an aggregate operation without an aggregation such as `group by`; this makes it hard to comment on the actual issue

Comment: This to me is a good example of why some new users find SO intimidating. English is probably not the OP's first language. He more than likely means Internet shop. The problem is reasonably clear to me as demonstrated by the upvoted answers below, but within minutes of asking there are close votes, and highly critical comments

Comment: I fixed the sql, sorry :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to aggregate the data first, this can be done using the `GROUP BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT (*), COUNT(DISTINCT Product_ID)
FROM table
GROUP BY Product_ID
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT Product_ID) DESC
```

The `DESC` keyword allows you to show the highest count first, `ORDER BY` by default orders in ascending order which would show the lowest count first.

Comment: to respect the intent of the question, `COUNT(*)` should IMO be `COUNT(Product_ID)` in both cases - which can be different depending on nulls; I suspect it should probably *actually* be either `COUNT(1)` or `COUNT(DISTINCT Product_ID)`, though

Comment: Can you explain what does group by do and do you mean: select *, count(product_id)?

Comment: Yes, `select *, count(DISTINCT product_id)` and regarding group by, read at: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-group-by.htm

Comment: So what should group be? (In the first line select GROUP)? I will really appreciate if you edit the sql you’ve written above

Comment: Group By  product_id (or any other column in your select that needed grouping)

Comment: hey man, i just used it in my c# code, and i got the error - Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'COUNT(DISTINCT Product_ID)'.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (*), Max(DISTINCT Product_ID)
FROM table
GROUP BY Product_ID
ORDER BY Max(DISTINCT Product_ID) DESC
```

the most sold item you use `max`